# Get html select value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a select element with id **ColorSelect** and I call a function to get the selected value of this element.

**My JavaScript function:**

```
function changeColor() {  
    var e = document.getElementById("ColorSelect").value;
    //var e = document.getElementById("ColorSelect").val;
    alert(e);
}
```

**And html select element:**

```
<select id="ColorSelect" onchange="changeColor()">
     @foreach (var sub in item.Kala.Colors)
     {
       <option  value="@sub.id" style="background-color:@sub.color">@sub.name</option>        
     }
     <!-- this part here makes option tag with different value -->
</select>
```

I have tried almost all the solution that I have found. How can I do it?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7wyon9v5/

Comment: @hev1 But it doesn't show the value

Comment: What do you mean by that? Does the alert not show?

Comment: @hev1 No. The alert shows but it has no value and just the ok button

Comment: I do see the value shown in the alert. Should I put it in a code snippet?

Comment: @ParhamHasaninia - hev1's example works just fine. Your posted code will work (though it's not best practice). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hev1 commented,your code is working fine but i think you can use a better approach, pass event as a parameter in changeColor

```
<select id="ColorSelect" onchange="changeColor(event)">
     @foreach (var sub in item.Kala.Colors)
     {
          <option  value="@sub.id" style="background-color:@sub.color">@sub.name</option>        
     }

</select>
```

now after passing you will be able to access it in changeColor function and can get value of select by event.target.value

```
function changeColor(event) {  
    alert(event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="ColorSelect" onchange="changeColor(this.value)">

@foreach (var sub in item.Kala.Colors)
{

<option  value="@sub.id" style="background-color:@sub.color">@sub.name</option> 

}

</select>
```

And javascript code should like this:

```
<script>
function changeColor(val) {
    alert(val);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should value of the select box by using this.value. and your function calling syntax should onchange="changeColor(this.value);" . If you use this and change select box value then  this.value take current value which you have selected.